# VIM is not aligned when commit code

Tags: git, vim

When using `vim`, in the terminal everything looks aligned but then after I commit some code I see that the alignments all off and a bunch of spaces have been added!! Please help!

Comment: You are adding tabs to the file.

Comment: You can use `:set list` and `:set listchars=tab:>-` to display them in Vim.

Comment: @FDinoff +1 'cos that's exactly what I thought, but then I read "… and a bunch of spaces have been added!!". So, now my theory is: spaces in a tab indented file.

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely caused by using both tabs and spaces as indentation characters it the same file. It can be easily solved by opening the file in vim and executing `:retab`

See `:h :retab` for more info.

**Why does it happen?**

Probably because your `shiftwidth` == `tabstops`. If for argument sake, both are set to `4`, then 4 spaces in VIM will appear to be the same width as a single TAB. However, in other editors, the width of those characters will be different, thus you end up with what looks like "broken alignment".

**Settings to check**

`:h 'expandtab'` - Controls if you want to use Spaces or Tabs for indent
`:h 'shiftwidth'` - Number of spaces to use for a single TAB
`:h 'tabstop'` - Number of spaces that a TAB in the file counts for